# Lower validation accuracy on ImageNet when evaluating Keras pre-trained models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagenet

I want to work with Keras models pre-trained on ImageNet. The models and information about their performance are [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models).

I downloaded ILSVRC 2012 ([ImageNet](https://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/2012-downloads.php)) dataset and evaluated ResNet50 on the validation dataset. The top-1 accuracy should be 0.749 but I get 0.68. The top-5 accuracy should be 0.921, mine is 0.884. I also tried VGG16 and MobileNet with similar discrepancies.

I preprocess the images using built-in preprocess_input function (e.g. `tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input()`).

My guess is that the dataset is different. How can I make sure that the validation dataset that I use for evaluation is the same as the one that was used by the authors? Could there be any other reason why I get different results?

Comment: how do you  resize and crop imagenet image ?

Comment: I use tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img